# Prove an inequality with the help of bernoulli equality and archimedian property.

Tags: inequality

I would like some help with the question below :

We have:
0 < q < 1.

Prove that for all ε > 0 there is M ∈ **N** (Natural number) , so for all n > M :

**q^n < ε.**

Hint:
Use Bernoulli Inequality and Archimedian Property.

For all those not sure what the hint is about :

**Bernoulli Inequality :**

[Bernoulli](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xAmeT.png)

**Archimedian Property :**

For every ε > 0 there is a n ∈ **N** : (1/n) < ε

I'm thankful for any kind of help. Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\frac{1}{q}=1+t$. Then $t$ is positive. By the Bernoulli inequality, if $n\gt 0$ we have
$$q^n=\frac{1}{(1+t)^n}\le \frac{1}{1+nt}\lt \frac{1}{nt}.$$
We want to make this $\lt \epsilon$.  Equivalently, we want $n\gt \frac{1}{t\epsilon}$. The Archimedean property tells us that there  is an integer $M$ such that $M\gt \frac{1}{t\epsilon}$.  And if $n\ge M$, it is clear that $n\gt \frac{1}{t\epsilon}$.

Comment: Much thanks, its quite easy now :( 

You are a real lifesaver :D

Comment: You are welcome. A single trick, rewriting $1/q$ as $1+t$, or if you prefer $q=\frac{1}{1+t}$, and the rest is downhill.